# Extended Controls makes android-studio crash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I create an avd in Android-studio (see below)
[image: android-Studio-avd-creation]

and run it,

I get these errors:

```
2024-03-28 03:31:39,572 [  91775]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 26 - Failed to process .ini file /home/bal/.android/avd/../avd/Pixel_6_Pro_API_26.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2024-03-28 03:31:39,668 [  91871]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 26 - FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
2024-03-28 03:31:39,932 [  92135]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 26 - The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
2024-03-28 03:31:39,937 [  92140]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 26 - *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
2024-03-28 03:31:40,091 [  92294]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 26 - Could not connect to proxy at :8888: No such file or directory !
2024-03-28 03:31:40,092 [  92295]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 26 - Proxy will be ignored !
2024-03-28 03:31:40,098 [  92301]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 26 - Device 'cache' does not have the requested snapshot 'default_boot'
2024-03-28 03:31:40,099 [  92302]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 26 - Failed to load snapshot 'default_boot'
2024-03-28 03:31:43,847 [  96050]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:44,884 [  97087]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:45,932 [  98135]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:46,982 [  99185]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:48,029 [ 100232]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:49,080 [ 101283]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:50,119 [ 102322]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:51,208 [ 103411]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:52,262 [ 104465]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:53,296 [ 105499]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:54,344 [ 106547]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:55,389 [ 107592]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:56,430 [ 108633]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:57,475 [ 109678]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:58,518 [ 110721]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:31:59,556 [ 111759]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:00,606 [ 112809]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:01,646 [ 113849]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:02,691 [ 114894]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:03,735 [ 115938]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:04,779 [ 116982]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:05,826 [ 118029]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:06,870 [ 119073]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:07,913 [ 120116]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:08,957 [ 121160]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:10,002 [ 122205]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-03-28 03:32:11,051 [ 123254]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
```

My avd is launched but when I click on Extended Controls here:
[image]

I get this box:
[image]

but then, my android-studio as well as my avd CRASHED and got these errors:

```
2024-03-28 03:34:04,395 [ 236598]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 26 - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
2024-03-28 03:35:09,678 [ 301881]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.analytics.SystemInfoStatsMonitor - CpuInfoFlags.fromExitCode(): unknown flag values '0x80'
```

this is my config:

```
..............                                     bal@kan 
            ..,;:ccc,.                             ------- 
          ......''';lxO.                           OS: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling x86_64 
.....''''..........,:ld;                           Kernel: 6.6.9-amd64 
           .';;;:::;,,.x,                          Uptime: 11 hours, 45 mins 
      ..'''.            0Xxoc:,.  ...              Packages: 3810 (dpkg), 4 (snap) 
  ....                ,ONkc;,;cokOdc',.            Shell: zsh 5.9 
 .                   OMo           ':ddo.          Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
                    dMc               :OO;         DE: Plasma 5.27.10 
                    0M.                 .:o.       WM: KWin 
                    ;Wd                            Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
                     ;XO,                          Icons: [Plasma], Flat-Remix-Purple-Dark [GTK2/3] 
                       ,d0Odlc;,..                 Terminal: konsole 
                           ..',;:cdOOd::,.         CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700X (16) @ 3.600GHz 
                                    .:d;.':;.      GPU: NVIDIA RTX A4000 
                                       'd,  .'     Memory: 8736MiB / 64218MiB 
                                         ;l   ..
                                          .o                               
                                            c                              
                                            .'
                                             .
```

I tried to change to run the avd directly from the terminal :

`emulator @Pixel_6_Pro_API_26 -writable-system`

but the errors are the same

the tried with this command:
`emulator @Pixel_6_Pro_API_26 -writable-system -gpu mode`

and got those errors:

```
┌──(bal㉿kan)-[~]
└─$ emulator @Pixel_6_Pro_API_26 -writable-system -gpu mode
INFO    | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/bal/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 2756013
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | System image is writable
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file /home/bal/.android/avd/../avd/Pixel_6_Pro_API_26.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
INFO    | Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
library_mode mode gpu mode mode
ERROR   | emuglConfig_init: Invalid GPU mode 'mode', use one of: host swiftshader_indirect. If you're already using one of those modes, the emulator installation may be corrupt. Please re-install the emulator. angle angle_indirect mesa swiftshader swiftshader_indirect
ERROR   | Invalid GPU mode 'mode', use one of: host swiftshader_indirect. If you're already using one of those modes, the emulator installation may be corrupt. Please re-install the emulator. angle angle_indirect mesa swiftshader swiftshader_indirect
WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
INFO    | Using security allow list from: /usr/lib/android-sdk/emulator/lib/emulator_access.json
WARNING | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
INFO    | The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: /run/user/1000/avd/running/2756013/jwks/4091ef5e-012c-42e8-ad0b-a6b10fb6c674/active.jwk
INFO    | Scanning /run/user/1000/avd/running/2756013/jwks/4091ef5e-012c-42e8-ad0b-a6b10fb6c674 for jwk keys.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_2756013.ini
WARNING | Could not connect to proxy at :8888: No such file or directory !
WARNING | Proxy will be ignored !
ERROR   | OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.

2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).

3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader".

Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.
ERROR   | crashhandler_die: fatal: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.

2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).

3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader".

Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.798655:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.798751:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.798964:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.799015:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.799070:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.799120:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.799174:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.799224:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.799276:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.799328:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.799380:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.799430:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756017:20240328,034319.799482:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[2756017:2756018:20240328,034319.807273:ERROR directory_reader_posix.cc:42] opendir /tmp/android-bal/emu-crash-33.1.24.db/attachments/8fca42c8-c8cd-433f-8782-e943dedb016c: No such file or directory (2)
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  emulator @Pixel_6_Pro_API_26 -writable-system -gpu mode
```

I am stuck here because I cannot access Extended Controls....

my objective is to add a proxy to avd